# Does Pandas have a `contracting` window function

Tags: python, pandas

Does Pandas have a `pandas.DataFrame.contracting` window function that would be the opposite of the [`pandas.DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) **without** having to sort the data first?  This would be similar to Spark's [`Window.unboundedFollowing`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=Window.unboundedFollowing#pyspark.sql.Window) as opposed to [`Window.unboundedPreceding`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=Window.unboundedPreceding#pyspark.sql.Window).

I assume it would be with `.rolling`

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

testdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]})

testdf['A'].expanding(min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x > 2).any()).tolist()

# [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

The following uses `.rolling` to produce the same results as above.

```
testdf['A'].rolling(window=len(testdf), min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x > 2).any()).tolist()

# [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

How would I change `.rolling` to work in the opposite direction?
Results should be:

```
# [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: What is the desired result? (I'm net entirely sure what `Window.unboundedFollowing` does.)

Comment: Are you looking for `testdf.loc[::-1, 'A'].expanding(min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x > 2).any())[::-1]`? This applies an expanding window to the Series in reversed order, then reverses that result, thus making the window contract.

Comment: Yes it is, Thank you.  Put it as an answer and I will accept it. However, I was hoping from something that did not involve sorting the Series, but this will do. Made some edits to make what I was looking for more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
testdf.loc[::-1, 'A'].expanding(min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x > 2).any())[::-1]
```

which yields

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
9    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

This applies an expanding window to the Series in reversed order, then reverses that result, thus making the window contract.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a option built into `expanding` for doing this.